# Add “http://” or “https://” to a URL that contain only the relative url starting by "www"

Tags: http, url, https

Could someone help me to fix this little code to add the protocol “http://” or “https://” to a URL that contain only the relative url starting by "www"

```
<script>
function formatUrl(url)
{
    var httpString = "http://";
    var httpsString = "https://";
    if (url.substr(0, httpString.length).toLowerCase() !== httpString && url.substr(0, httpsString.length).toLowerCase() !== httpsString)
                url = httpString + url;
    return url;
}
</script>



  <form id=url type=get action='answers.asp'  >
  <input type=text name=URL size=10 value="" ><br><br>
  <input type=submit name=url2  **onclick="formatUrl()"** value="Enter Url">
  </form>
```

Input value = www.elmundo.es or any other relative url starting by www

thank you in advance

Answer (score -1):

Actually this is a pretty simple task:

```
function formatURL(url)
{
    if(url.substr(0,3) === "www")
    {
        return "https://"+url;
    }
    return url;
}
```

You may add some additional fail-safe checks (if the url is smaller than 3) - but you usually can check if the url starts with www, if so, you simply add the desired protocol to it (if I understood your question properly).

Ah, I guess now I got what you were asking for.

```
<script>
function formatURL()
{
    var url = document.getElementsByName("URL")[0];
    var formattedURL = document.getElementsByName("formattedURL")[0];
    url = url.value;
    if(url.substr(0,3) === "www")
    {
        formattedURL.value = "https://"+url;
        return;
    }
    formattedURL.value = url;
}
</script>

<form id=url type=get action='answers.asp'>
  <input type="text" name="URL" size=10 value=""  onchange="formatURL()"><br><br>
  <input type="hidden" name="formattedURL">
  <input type="submit" value="Enter Url">
  </form>
```

This will set the URL formatted into the hidden field `formattedURL` - however, this is only if you really want to do this in Javascript completely. I would do this on the server side, personally.

Comment: Very pretty, however I cannot change the url properly before submit

Comment: see my edit, hopefully that was what you were looking for.

Comment: Wow!!! Now it is working fine. Very useful code. I need only to give the option to both protocol https and http (like your first code)

Comment: How I can evaluate your helpful?

Comment: So you were able to add the stuff with the protocols yourself? Great! You can rate an answer as helpful with the arrows on the right.

Comment: Unfortunately not. It is working fine for http or https. I was not able to add the both protocols for running correctly. I have changed the variables, the if else statement , logical operators. However many thnks for your script which works fine with http or https.